# How to operate on value in Create CSV step of Logic App?

Tags: export-to-csv, azure-logic-apps

I need to multiply the max_pay__c item in a record by 0.95 before including it in CSV table. What is the best method for that?

[image]

I've tried using ...

```
@mul(item()?['max_pay_c'],0.95)
```

... function, but that seems to use NULL for `item()?['max_pay_c']`

These are the first few records from "Get records" :

```
{
  "body": {
    "value": [
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "ccbce48a-cf62-4e3f-bd56-94b90764e1ca",
        "Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-30T18:00:00Z",
        "Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-30T14:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-17T21:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-17T13:00:00Z",
        "Weight__c": 30250,
        "dest_city__c": "WARMINSTER",
        "dest_state__c": "PA",
        "dest_zip__c": "18974",
        "max_pay__c": 850,
        "orig_zip__c": "23320",
        "origin_city__c": "CHESAPEAKE",
        "origin_state__c": "VA"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "3eac0b25-bde8-4185-89c0-0b15827d13ff",
        "Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-20T13:30:00Z",
        "Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-20T13:30:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-16T22:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-16T14:00:00Z",
        "Weight__c": 38845,
        "dest_city__c": "MILWAUKIE",
        "dest_state__c": "OR",
        "dest_zip__c": "97222",
        "max_pay__c": 6316.132222873688,
        "orig_zip__c": "78045",
        "origin_city__c": "LAREDO",
        "origin_state__c": "TX"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "e6f249a6-dd8f-4e4f-8de7-d1e37d611896",
        "Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-18T18:00:00Z",
        "Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-18T14:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-17T21:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-17T13:00:00Z",
        "Weight__c": 30250,
        "dest_city__c": "WARMINSTER",
        "dest_state__c": "PA",
        "dest_zip__c": "18974",
        "max_pay__c": 900,
        "orig_zip__c": "23320",
        "origin_city__c": "CHESAPEAKE",
        "origin_state__c": "VA"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "a2593a84-a224-4e78-bdf0-184d4ad112bd",
        "Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-23T13:30:00Z",
        "Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-23T13:30:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-18T17:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-18T17:00:00Z",
        "Weight__c": 42640,
        "dest_city__c": "MILWAUKIE",
        "dest_state__c": "OR",
        "dest_zip__c": "97222",
        "max_pay__c": 5700,
        "orig_zip__c": "08837",
        "origin_city__c": "EDISON",
        "origin_state__c": "NJ"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "be8ba5c3-ea31-4da5-9369-17055c3776c2",
        "Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-18T16:00:00Z",
        "Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-18T16:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-16T18:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-16T18:00:00Z",
        "Weight__c": 24624,
        "dest_city__c": "FOREST PARK",
        "dest_state__c": "GA",
        "dest_zip__c": "30297",
        "max_pay__c": 2700,
        "orig_zip__c": "78045",
        "origin_city__c": "LAREDO",
        "origin_state__c": "TX"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "05b6dfb9-f502-4de5-b6b4-827c18706c33",
        "Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-13T16:00:00Z",
        "Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-13T16:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c": "2023-01-12T19:00:00Z",
        "Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c": "2023-01-12T19:00:00Z",
        "Weight__c": 35998,
        "dest_city__c": "PHILADELPHIA",
        "dest_state__c": "PA",
        "dest_zip__c": "19154",
        "max_pay__c": 655.6680024414063,
        "orig_zip__c": "21075",
        "origin_city__c": "ELKRIDGE",
        "origin_state__c": "MD"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `item()` is only used in a loop.  Can you show us the output of the Salesforce step above?

Comment: The actual output of the Salesforce step has 200 records, so I'll include one here:

        "value": [
            {
                "@odata.etag": "",
                "ItemInternalId": "0db0041a-8e95-47f8-b517-d54a4f692714",
                "Weight__c": 30250,
                "dest_city__c": "WARMINSTER",
                "dest_state__c": "PA",
                "dest_zip__c": "18974",
                "max_pay__c": 850,
                "orig_zip__c": "23320",
                "origin_city__c": "CHESAPEAKE",
                "origin_state__c": "VA"
            }

Comment: You need to add it to your question, not here as a comment. Also, It may have 200+ but remove 197 of them and then supply everything else that is left. I want to see the exact structure of the response coming back. It doesn’t have to include all array values though. Again, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've posted a few more records above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the variable that you are trying to pass is actually `max_pay__c` but you are using `max_pay_c` for your expression. After making that change from my end, this was working fine. Below is the expression I'm using.

```
mul(items('For_each')?['max_pay__c'],0.95)
```

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need first find the datatype for max_pay_c.

Let's suppose it is a nullable integer, you need to add some extra logic to handle that, like:

mul(0.95,if(equals(item()?['max_pay_c'], null),0,item()?['max_pay_c']))

either that or something to skip the calculation when null